# No puedo abrir una URL desde el evento click del boton en visual studio 2002

Tags: visual-studio

Estoy creando una forma  en windows  con visual studio 2022 y  quiero usar un botón para que me abra una página  de internet pero me sale este error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'https://www.google.com.mx/' with working directory 'C:\Users\alext\Documents\WindowsForms'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.'

este es mi código:

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Process.Start("https://www.google.com.mx/");
           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar el siguiente código el cual debería funcionar perfectamente para abrir la url:

```
var ps = new ProcessStartInfo("https://www.google.com.mx/")
{ 
   UseShellExecute = true, 
   Verb = "open" 
};
Process.Start(ps);
```

Espero haberte ayudado, Saludos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente qué hace este código. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._